# How to delete entries from a dictionary using the value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

I have a dictionary collection as bleow:

```
mydic.addvalue(key1, val1)
mydic.addvalue(key2, val1)
mydic.addvalue(key3, val1)
mydic.addvalue(key4, val2)
mydic.addvalue(key5, val2)
```

From the above dictionary I want to delete all the entries where value == "val1", so that the result would have only following entry:

```
mydic.addvalue(key4, val2)
mydic.addvalue(key5, val2)
```

My VB source code is on VS2008 and targeted for 3.5

Comment: And the types of the key and value are?

Comment: @user: it's not a C# dictionary. It's the .NET Framework `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A non-LINQ answer based on a comment by the user.

```
private static void RemoveByValue<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TValue someValue)
{
    List<TKey> itemsToRemove = new List<TKey>();

    foreach (var pair in dictionary)
    {
        if (pair.Value.Equals(someValue))
            itemsToRemove.Add(pair.Key);
    }

    foreach (TKey item in itemsToRemove)
    {
        dictionary.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "foo");
dictionary.Add(2, "foo");
dictionary.Add(3, "bar");
string someValue = "foo";
RemoveByValue(dictionary, someValue);
```

Same caveat as with the other answers: if your value determines equality by reference, you'll need to do extra work. This is just a base.

Comment: "if your value determines equality by reference, you'll need to do extra work. This is just a base." --> Hi can you pls elaborate on what you mean by "if your value determines equality by reference"?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, it means does it check to see if two variables literally refer to the same instance. Picture `Foo a = new Foo(); Foo b = new Foo();` While both a and b hold references to an empty Foo, they do not refer to the *same* Foo. In `Foo a = new Foo(); Foo b = a;`, a and b refer to the same instance. If you need the earlier example to compare as equal, you need to do more work, which could involve overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the class, or providing an `IEqualityCompare<T>` for the class.

Answer (score 15):

You first need to find all keys for which the associated value is `val1`:

```
var keysToRemove = mydic.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == val1)
                        .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
                        .ToArray();
```

Then you can remove each of those keys:

```
foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
{
    mydic.Remove(key);
}
```

Comment: This. But (@user) keep in mind that you'll need to do extra work for equality if the TValue is a reference type (unless you're fine just comparing references, that is). Also the `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` is absolutely necessary in order to iterate over the results in a foreach *and* modify the original dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I know this may sound silly, but what is kvp? since I have never worked on linQ

Comment: @user, in this case, it is merely shorthand for KeyValuePar. But the name itself is unimportant in this context, it could be *anything*. Look into lambdas, but the short short version is that in `(kvp => kvp.Value == val1)`, `kvp` is the name of the supplied argument (in this case a KeyValuePair), and `kvp.Value == val1` is the expression that evaluates to true or false. This is because a LINQ Where clause uses a function that takes in a typed parameter and returns a bool.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can this be done without using LinQ?

Comment: @user, I'll post a non-LINQ answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
var x= (from k in mydic
           where k.Value != val1
           select k).ToDictionary(k=>k.key);
```

x will not have any of the val1's

Comment: But it will also be a new dictionary. Any references to the original dictionary would now be useless unless they are uninterested in keys/values that have been removed (or added, altered, etc.).

Comment: Better solution would be the first one 
            var keys = (from d in mydic
                        where d.Value == "val1"
                        select d.Key).ToList();
            
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
              
                    mydic.Remove(key);
           
            }

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var key in dict.AllKeys.ToArray())
{
    if(...)
        //remove key or something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer it's old but this is how I do the same thing without create another Dictionary.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> x in MyDic) {

  if (x.Value == "val1")) 
  {  MyDic.Remove(x.Key); } 
}
```