# deleting key,value pairs from a dictionary given a list of keys to delete

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a `List<string> AllowedList` and a `Dictionary<string,List<string>> MyDictionary`.

For each key in the dictionary, I want to check if it's on the `AllowedList`, if not I want to delete the key and value from the dictionary.

I intuitively tried this which seems to be what I wanted:

```
foreach (string key in MyDictionary.Keys)
{
    if (!AllowedList.Contains(key)) MyDictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

However, I encountered an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I'm sure there's probably a simple way around this, but I don't immediately see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Except` to find the keys that are not in the dictionary:

```
foreach (var key in MyDictionary.Keys.Except(AllowedList).ToList())
    MyDictionary.Remove(key);
```

The `ToList()` creates a new list of the set difference and prevents the exception.

Comment: +1 and I think the first line can be simplified to `var keys = MyDictionary.Keys;`

Comment: Seismoid's solution is also a valid one.  I do enjoy this linq set difference suggestion the most, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could/should store the keys you want to delete in a temporary list and do all the removing in an extra for-loop after that.

```
List<TKey> templist = new List<TKey>();

foreach (var x in MyDictionary)
{
    if (!AllowedList.Contains(x.Key))
        templist .Add(x.Key);
}
foreach (TKey item in templist )
{
    MyDictionary.Remove(item);
}
```

this could also be helpful:
[How to delete entries from a dictionary using the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992001/how-to-delete-entries-from-a-dictionary-using-the-value)